Evaporation of a liquid
This is a problem in Callen's book (9.7-3).
The phase diagram of a solution of $A$ in $B$, at a pressure of 1 atm and in the region of small mole fraction ($x_A\ll 1$), is as shown. The upper bounding curve of the two-phase region can be represented by
$$ T=T_0-C x_A $$
and the lower bounding curve by
$$ T=T_0-D x_A $$
in which $C$ and $D$ are positive constants (D>C).
Assume that a liquid of mole fraction $x_A^0$ is brought to a boil and kept boiling until only a fraction $N_f/N_i$ of the material remains; derive an expression for the final mole fraction of $A$.
Show that if $D=3C$ and if $N_f/N_i=\frac{1}{2}$, the final mole fraction of component $A$ is one fourth its initial value.

Now I have no difficulty working out the $1/4$ value Callen gave.
Suppose at a particular state during the vaporization, the mole fraction of $A$ is $x_A$, then the boiling temperature is $T_0-Dx_A$. At this temperature, the mole fraction of $A$ in the vapor is $x_A'=(D/C)x_A$.
If $(-dN)$ moles out of $N$ moles of liquid is boiled off, the mole fraction of A in the remaining liquid is then
$$ x_A+dx_A=\frac{x_A N-(-x_A' dN)}{N-(-dN)}=x_A+(x_A'-x_A)\frac{dN}{N} $$
This reduces to
$$ dx_A=\left(\frac{D}{C}-1\right)x_A\frac{dN}{N} $$
Integrating this from the initial state to the final state, we have
$$ x_A^f=x_A^0\left(\frac{N_f}{N_i}\right)^{D/C-1} $$
If we plugin the values $D/C=3$ and $N_f/N_i=1/2$, we obtain $x_A^f=\frac{1}{4}x_A^0$, as is given by Callen.
However, I doubt that the mole fraction of $A$ in the liquid can get this low.

This figure comes from Schroeder's book discussing the liquification of air. It shows that if all the original air is condensed into liquid, the mole fraction of oxygen in the liquid is the same as that in the original air. We could apply this same logic to Callen's problem.

The maximum temperature we can get into is determined by setting $x_A=x_A^o$ in the equation of the upper bounding curve
$$ T_\text{max}=T_0-Cx_A^0. $$
From the figure, it is seen that the smallest mole fraction of $A$ is obtained by setting $T=T_\text{max}$ in the lower bounding curve:
$$ x_A=\frac{C}{D}x_A^0=\frac{1}{3}x_A^0>\frac{1}{4}x_A^0 $$
Thus Callen's 1/4 fraction cannot be reached.
Furthermore, at $T_\text{max}$, all liquid should have vaporized, so $N_f$ (the mole number of the remaining liquid) should be $0$, contradicting $N_f/N_i=1/2$. If we set $N_f=0$ in
$$ x_A^f=x_A^0\left(\frac{N_f}{N_i}\right)^{D/C-1} $$
we obtain
$$ x_A^f = 0 $$
This means that if all liquid become gas, we are at the very top left of the phase diagram (where the two bounding curves intersect), at $T_0>T_\text{max}$. This is another contradiction.
My question is, is there any flaw in my reasoning?

This is the difference between a closed system and an open system.
In the Callen problem, it's assumed that the vapor escapes from the system. Your first analysis is correct under that assumption.
In the Schroeder analysis, it's assumed that the condensation (or boiling) occurs in a closed vessel and that no mass enters or leaves the system. Your second analysis is correct under that assumption.
